# What does "F" mean in "Mushrooms 3.94 F" of my grocery receipt?

Tags: meaning

What does "F" mean in "Mushrooms 3.94 F" of my grocery receipt? I guess it means I paid 3.94 US dollars for mushrooms, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

F on a grocery receipt generally refers to whether or not it was a food item.  Food items are not usually taxable, whereas other types of items, such as general merchandise, are.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Is something taxable more expensive than when it is not taxable? (2) Does an item taxable mean customers have to pay tax for buying the item?

Comment: Taxable means you have to pay a tax on the item.  This is usually expressed as a certain percentage of the entire cost.  In the state of New York, tax is generally 8 percent.  So a taxable item that costs $10 would be $10.80 with the tax.  So, yes, taxable items are more expensive.

Comment: More: this is the *sales tax*.  (Of course there are also other taxes not intended by this answer.)